# Loading Facelets templates from database

Tags: database, jsf, templates, facelets, jsf-2.2

In my application (CMS for internal purposes) I'm facing the problem how to serve pages stored in the database with dynamic URL (e.g. `http://example.com/page3`) using the JSF. Generally, let's say I want to grab the page content from the database, put it inside jsf file and serve it as `/page3`. Is there any way how to obtain the request URL from JSF, search the database for the article (instead of searching *xhtml in the WAR), build dynamically the JSF XHML file and return it to JSF as InputStream for example? I've found [this answed by Thomas Maerz](https://community.jboss.org/thread/141138), but it failed with

```
Unable to create a new instance of 'com.test.CustomResourceResolver': java.lang.InstantiationException: com.test.CustomResourceResolver
```

on my glassfish v4 (Mojarra 2.2), and I also found that [ResourceResolver is deprecated in JSF2.2](http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-22/#809).

I've googled a lot, but this seems to be not very common/documented part of JSF.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Could you add full stack-trace and relevant lines of your code?

Answer (score -1):

I did not understand fully the problem, but for url change you can use prettyfaces, for dynamic forms you can use primefaces ext and I am not suggest keep form in the database, if I know your target I can suggest more useful answer.